# 2 ГОСТ криптопровайдера на одной машине

Tags: криптография, гост

Возможно ли одновременное использование 2 разных криптопровайдеров ГОСТ на одной машине?
Например, CryptoPro CSP и SignalCOM CSP или Tumar CSP.
Если нет, то какова причина?

Comment: Хотелось бы знать состояние проблемы на текущий момент? Может что то изменилось в лучшую сторону?

Answer (score 1):

Беглый осмотр гугла дал мне вот что:

> Адресовал его техподдержке компании "Сигнал-КОМ", получен ответ что на одной
>   операционной системе криптопровайдеры "КриптоПро CSP" и "Signal-COM CSP" не
>   уживутся, тестовые испытания ими уже проводились. Каждый криптопровайдер
>   нужно ставить на отдельную операционную систему.
>   ( источник: http://www.cryptopro.ru/forum2/default.aspx?g=posts&t=7057 )

Comment: Хотелось бы знать состояние проблемы на текущий момент? Может что то изменилось в лучшую сторону? Я знаю что совместная работа Crypto Pro и VipNet возможна. Почему в других случаях совместная работа безуспешна.

Comment: Имхо, лучше всего эту информацию запросить у поставщиков или техподдержки ПО

Comment: Поставщики обычно отвечают только за свой продукт и советуют просто удалить то, что им мешает

Comment: Думаю спросить всё равно стоит, тем более, в приведенном ответе, я процитировал ответ техподдержки и судя по нему - они всё же проверяют совместимость. Попробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

> Если нет, то какова причина?

Есть предположение - причина в простоте реализации клиентского ПО, которое использует всегда реализацию криптоалгоритма по умолчанию.

Прочтите статью http://rsdn.ru/article/crypto/cspsecrets.xml

Где есть такой текст и код:

> Следующий код устанавливает провайдер по умолчанию для определенного типа.

```
#define YOUR_PROV_NAME "MY_PROV"
#define YOUR_PROV_TYPE 75

rc = CryptSetProvider(
    YOUR_PROV_NAME,
    YOUR_PROV_TYPE
);
```

Если два криптопровайдера при установке ставят себя - криптопровайдером по умолчанию для определённого типа, то они неуживутся.

Это и хорошо и плохо:

- С одной стороны хорошо. В клиентском ПО иногда ИД криптопровайдера задан в коде (не настраивается) и если пользователь, использующий CryptoPro, поставит SignalCOM, то его программное обеспечение не заметит разницы и будет работать как прежде.
- С другой стороны плохо. Если пользователь использует несколько CSP, они конфликтуют, то кто последний установлен - тот и CSP, реализующий ГОСТ.

Например, есть такая константа в WinCryptEx.h:
`var PROV_GOST_2001_DH = 75`, после установки КриптоПро она соответствует `Crypto-Pro GOST R 34.10-2001 Cryptographic Service Provider`.

Также есть константа `PROV_GOST_DH = 2`, после установки VipNet она соотвествует `ViPNet Cryptographic Service Provider`

Согласно статье http://v8.1c.ru/edi/edi_app/1c-taxcom/faq/?printversion=1 :

- КриптоПро CSP: "Crypto-Pro GOST R 34.10-2001 Cryptographic Service Provider" (тип 75),
- ViPNet CSP: "Infotecs Cryptographic Service Provider" (тип 2),
- Signal-COM CPGOST Cryptographic Provider (тип 75);
- ЛИССИ-CSP (тип 75).

Таким образом, ViPNet не конфликтует с Crypto-Pro. А Signal-COM конфликтует с КриптоПро CSP, если клиентское ПО использует всегда реализацию алгоритма по умолчанию и не может выбирать между криптопровайдерами.

Вывод - надо писать настраиваемое клиентское ПО или делать такие криптопровайдеры, у которых тип будет не `2` и не `75`, а с каким-то другим значением.